# Can't add property to object (Cannot set property of undefined)

Tags: javascript, object, properties, set, addition

I am having problems with adding properties to an object. I want it to, when you click like, it will create a new property inside the "scores"-object and then increment that value by one. But I am getting this error when doing this:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '(hex-code)' of undefined

HTML

```
<p style="display: inline;">Hex-code: </p>
<input id="demo" type="text">
<button onclick="generate()">Generate</button>

<div id="showcase" style="background: #FFF; width: 200px; height: 200px; margin: 20px; border-radius: 3px;"></div>

<button onclick="like()">Like</button>
<button onclick="dislike()">Dislike</button>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var result = document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML;
var hex;

var scores = {}

function generate () {
    var length = 3,
        charset = "ABCDEF0123456789",
        retVal = "";
    for (var i = 0, n = charset.length; i < length; ++i) {
        retVal += charset.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * n));
    }
    finalVal = "#" + retVal;
    document.getElementById('demo').value = finalVal;
    document.getElementById('showcase').style.backgroundColor = finalVal;
    return hex = retVal;
}

function like () {
    scores[hex] = 0;
    scores[hex] += 1;
    return generate();
}
```

Link to fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/elliotsoomro/o0kuwc0d/4/

Comment: "hex" is set in `generate()`, but generate isn't called until the end of like(), which means that the first time like() is called, hex will not have a value. you need to initialize hex. instead of `var hex;` change to `var hex=0;`

Comment: This is the actual error that breaks everything after: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null`

Comment: your code will work if you put code inside javascript. Change settings in Javascript code area inside jsfiddle. [Working code](https://jsfiddle.net/o0kuwc0d/6/)

Comment: @Michael okay, thanks! I'll do that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have included your script in the `<head>` of your html, without wrapping it in `window.onload`. This will make this line fail

```
var result = document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML;
```

because the element isn't found at runtime, which further leads to `score` being never defined because of above breaking error.

See [this updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o0kuwc0d/5/) with the working script beeing included in the html's `<body>`. Alternatively, you could just wrap the first part of your code within `window.onload = function() {}` or just put the

```
var result = document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML;
```

in your `generate()` function.

Comment: thanks a lot! very new to programming, amazing support from this website!